# How to make SwiftUI grid with variable number of columns depending on available space in parent view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am developing an iOS-iPadOS app with SwiftUI.
I have a collection of images I want to be displayed in different row sizes (all the row must be equal length) filling much of parent view (an edge to edge List cell). It’s very straightforward doing so if you know how many columns or row you need. Instead I would like adaptable code device-agnostic. Size classes (regular and compact) are not an option since iPad split screen and iPhone landscape are compact but have much horizontal space.

I looked for a way of getting view size, although I don’t think it’s a good approach. I found nothing.

This is base code I used para while constructing layout (still unadapted to accept rows or columns number of table):

```swift
VStack(alignment: .center){
    HStack(alignment: .center){
        Spacer()
        ForEach(lista.prefix(5)) { periodo in
            Group{
            Image(systemName:"\(periodo.imagen).circle.fill")
            .resizable()
            .foregroundColor(color(periodo.color))
            .frame(width: 55, height: 55)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.periodoActual = self.lista.firstIndex(of: periodo) ?? 0
            }
            Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10){
        ForEach(lista.dropFirst(5)) { periodo in
            Image(systemName:"\(periodo.imagen).circle.fill")
            .resizable()
            .foregroundColor(color(periodo.color))
            .frame(width: 55, height: 55)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.periodoActual = self.lista.firstIndex(of: periodo) ?? 0
            }
        }
    }
}.frame(minWidth: 0, idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity)
```

Where lista is an array (its length is 10) containing instances of custom structure decoded from JSON file. periodoActual is a state variable (@State).

Has someone got an idea for effectively approaching this problem?
Thanks in advance.